# How can I remove a screw-less spindle tap when I can’t reach the bonnet nut?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have a pair of spindle taps in the wall at my laundry sink. They have screwless tap handles, I.e. the handles are somehow compression fitted onto the spindle shafts, and don’t seem to be removable.

I want to change the washer, since it’s squealing when in certain positions, but I’m not sure how to actually get it off. I also plan to replace these taps with a more traditional spindle tap fitting that has easily removable handles at some point in the near future.

I’ve been able to remove the hot tap by opening the tap all the way, then unscrewing the flange/cover until there was *just* enough of a gap between the tiles and the flange to fit a spanner in and unscrew the bonnet.

The cold tap, however, is recessed into the wall about 5-10mm further, so the nut on the bonnet sits below the tiles, making it impossible to use any kind of normal spanner or grips to access it, no matter how thin they are.

Is it possible or safe to unscrew the whole tap assembly by just opening the taps all the way, then using a wrench to turn the handle itself? If this is the only way to get it off, is that how it must’ve been originally installed? (Tightening the whole assembly by applying pressure to the handle itself)

The only alternative I can see is using some sort of “angled pliers” or something that can somehow grab the nut on an angle from the tiny gap under the flange.

[image]
This photo shows the tap with the handle all the way out - there’s only about 7-8mm clearance between the cover and the back of the handle, so when you unscrew the cover.

[image]
This photo shows the tiny amount of access you can get when you unscrew the cover and push the flange to the side - it’s extremely tight, and there’s no way you can get a wrench behind the flange/cover.

---

**Edit:** after looking at the photos and noticing a dark mark in the reflection, then inspecting more closely with a mirror, there appears to be 2 very small notches (180° apart) on the backside of the handles, which I’m guessing may mean that the handles use the “anti-vandal” removal mechanism.

Comment: A picture would clarify your problem for the rest of us. Please consider [edit]ing one in, using the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box.

Comment: Done, photos added.

Comment: That escutcheon/flange at the "wall" won't move?